# What does Database.AddInParameter() method do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enterprise-library, data-access-layer

I was debugging datahandler for an mvc4 application, and I came across the

```
AddInParameter(DbCommand, String, DbType);
```

and I looked for the same in MSDN, but there its mentioned as retired content and there is not much documentation. So please anybody help me to understand what it does?

Comment: In my own understanding : DbCommand = how a certain query will be executed e.g. update/insert, String is the value/argument that will be used by DbCommand,  DbType is a dataType for the field in your target datasource provider. Again, this is just my interpretation and have not used this.

Answer (score 1):

1st Parameter, DbCommand - is the command you want to execute on your database, e.g. StoredProc, SqlString etc.
2nd Parameter, Parameter Name - is the name of your parameter
3rd DbType, DbType - is the type of your parameter e.g. String

Basically this will add an Input parameter which can be used in your DbCommand. The AddInParmeter method works similarly like the SqlCommand.Parameters.Add() of the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.